# Reporting Errors In Spring Boot Startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, messagebox

When my application.yml does not match the database schema properly in my springboot application it will fail to start with a very verbose exception trace.

This trace is very difficult for a user to parse, even if I log the failure reason, it will be lost in a barrage of logs.

Worse yet, if the user launcher the program from a shortcut it will disappear and they will need to dig up the log or run it from the command line.

I would like to popup a message box right when I encounter the problem.

I tried adding a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` but this throws a  java.awt.HeadlessException.

Is there a more canonical way to provide user feedback when a spring boot application fails to start?

Comment: Most of the time with log.level=INFO we got the exact error. If log.level=TRACE then you will definitely get lot of logs.

Comment: Can you try once with INFO and see if that helps

Comment: Yes, changing the log level can help a bit....I added some notes about running from shortcut and why I need a better mechanism than logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot app [is headless by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#headless-boolean-) - it means there is no GUI supposed.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog - is part of GUI Java Swing framework.

So to use this GUI feature, you need to make you Spring Boot not headless.

Example (short version of code from [here](https://zetcode.com/articles/springbootswing/)):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSbSwingApplication extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoSbSwingApplication.class)
                .headless(false)
                .run(args);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            var ex = ctx.getBean(DemoSbSwingApplication.class);
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public DemoSbSwingApplication() {
        var pane = getContentPane();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane, "TEST TEST TEST");
    }

}
```